# Why is Flask-Migrate making me do a 2-steps migration?

Tags: flask, alembic, flask-migrate

I'm working on a project with Flask, SQLAlchemy, Alembic and their wrappers for Flask (Flask-SQLAlchemy and Flask-Migrate). I have four migrations:

```
1c5f54d4aa34 -> 4250dfa822a4 (head), Feed: Countries
312c1d408043 -> 1c5f54d4aa34, Feed: Continents
41984a51dbb2 -> 312c1d408043, Basic Structure
<base> -> 41984a51dbb2, Init Alembic
```

When I start a new and clean database and try to run the migrations I get an error:

```
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant$ python manage.py db upgrade
...
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) relation "continent" does not exist
...
```

If I ask Flask-Migrate to run all migrations but the last, it works. If after that I run the upgrade command again, it works – that is, it fully upgrades my database without a single change in code:

```
vagrant@precise32:/vagrant$ python manage.py db upgrade 312c1d408043
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Running upgrade  -> 41984a51dbb2, Init Alembic
INFO  [alembic.migration] Running upgrade 41984a51dbb2 -> 312c1d408043, Basic Structure

vagrant@precise32:/vagrant$ python manage.py db upgrade
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Running upgrade 312c1d408043 -> 1c5f54d4aa34, Feed: Continents
INFO  [alembic.migration] Running upgrade 1c5f54d4aa34 -> 4250dfa822a4, Feed: Countries
```

**TL;DR**

The last migration (Feed: Countries) run queries on the table fed by the previous one (Feed: Continents). If I have the continents table create and fed, the scripts should work. But it doesn't.
Why do I have to stop the migration process between then to re-start it in another command? I really don't get this. Is it some command Alembic executes after a serie of migrations? Any ideas?

**Just in case**

My models are defined as follows:

```py
class Country(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'country'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    alpha2 = db.Column(db.String(2), index=True, unique=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(140))
    continent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('continent.id'))
    continent = db.relationship('Continent', backref='countries')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Country #{}: {}>'.format(self.id, self.title)

class Continent(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'continent'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    alpha2 = db.Column(db.String(2), index=True, unique=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(140))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Continent #{}: {}>'.format(self.id, self.title)
```

Many thanks,

**UPDATE 1: The upgrade method of the last two migrations**

As @Miguel asked in a comment, here there are the upgrade methods of the last two migrations:

*Feed: Continents*

```py
def upgrade():
    csv_path = app.config['BASEDIR'].child('migrations', 'csv', 'en')
    csv_file = csv_path.child('continents.csv')
    with open(csv_file) as file_handler:
        csv = list(reader(file_handler))
        csv.pop(0)
        data = [{'alpha2': c[0].lower(), 'title': c[1]} for c in csv]
        op.bulk_insert(Continent.__table__, data)
```

*Feed: Countries* (which depends on the table fed on the last migration)

```py
def upgrade():

    # load countries iso3166.csv and build a dictionary
    csv_path = app.config['BASEDIR'].child('migrations', 'csv', 'en')
    csv_file = csv_path.child('iso3166.csv')
    countries = dict()
    with open(csv_file) as file_handler:
        csv = list(reader(file_handler))
        for c in csv:
            countries[c[0]] = c[1]

    # load countries-continents from country_continent.csv
    csv_file = csv_path.child('country_continent.csv')
    with open(csv_file) as file_handler:
        csv = list(reader(file_handler))
        country_continent = [{'country': c[0], 'continent': c[1]} for c in csv]

    # loop
    data = list()
    for item in country_continent:

        # get continent id
        continent_guess = item['continent'].lower()
        continent = Continent.query.filter_by(alpha2=continent_guess).first()

        # include country
        if continent is not None:
            country_name = countries.get(item['country'], False)
            if country_name:
                data.append({'alpha2': item['country'].lower(),
                             'title': country_name,
                             'continent_id': continent.id})
```

The CSV I'm using are basically following this patterns:

*continents.csv*

```
...
AS, "Asia"
EU, "Europe"
NA, "North America"
...
```

*iso3166.csv*

```
...
CL,"Chile"
CM,"Cameroon"
CN,"China"
...
```

_country_continent.csv_

```
...
US,NA
UY,SA
UZ,AS
...
```

So *Feed: Continents* feeds the continent table, and *Feed: Countries* feeds the country table. But it has to query the continents table in order to make the proper link between the country and the continent.

**UPDATE 2: Some one from Reddit already offered an explanation and a workaround**

I asked [the same question on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/2p7hpf/af_flaskmigrate_why_i_need_to_do_a_2_steps_upgrade/cmua7az), and [themathemagician](http://www.reddit.com/user/themathemagician) said:

> I've run into this before, and the issue is that the migrations don't
>   execute individually, but instead alembic batches all of them (or all
>   of them that need to be run) and then executes the SQL. This means
>   that by the time the last migration is trying to run, the tables don't
>   actually exist yet so you can't actually make queries. Doing
>
> ```
> from alembic import op
>
> def upgrade():
>     #migration stuff
>     op.execute('COMMIT')
>     #run queries
> ```
>
> This isn't the most elegant solution (and that was for Postgres, the
>   command may be different for other dbs), but it worked for me. Also,
>   this isn't actually an issue with Flask-Migrate as much as an issue
>   with alembic, so if you want to Google for more info, search for
>   alembic. Flask-Migrate is just a wrapper around alembic that works
>   with Flask-Script easily.

Comment: Can you add the `upgrade()` methods of the last two migrations?

Comment: @Miguel, thanks, just edited the post and added the methods. BTW, [elsewhere](https://github.com/cuducos/whiskyton#thanks) I’ve said “thank you” to you, but maybe you haven’t seen it – so, just sharing once more haha…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As indicated by @themathemagician on reddit, Alembic by default runs all the migrations in a single transaction, so depending on the database engine and what you do in your migration scripts, some operations that depend on things added in a previous migration may fail.

I haven't tried this myself, but Alembic 0.6.5 introduced a `transaction_per_migration` option, which might address this. This is an option to the `configure()` call in `env.py`. If you are using the default config files as Flask-Migrate creates them, then this is where you fix this in `migrations/env.py`:

```
def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    # ...
    context.configure(
                connection=connection,
                target_metadata=target_metadata,
                transaction_per_migration=True        # <-- add this
                )
    # ...
```

Also note that if you plan to also run offline migrations you need to fix the `configure()` call in the `run_migrations_offline()` in the same way.

Give this a try and let me know if it addresses the problem.